# Probability generating function and expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be Poisson random variable with parameter $Y$, where $Y$ is Poisson random variable, with parameter $\mu$. Prove that, $G_{X+Y}(s)=\exp\{\mu (s\exp^{s-1}-1)\}$

I know that, Poisson r.v. generating function is $G(s)=\exp\{\lambda(s-1)\}$. Do I need to calculate joint probability distribution first ($P(Z)$), where $Z=X+Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: As recalled in the post, $E[s^X\mid Y]=\exp\{Y(s-1)\}$ hence $G_{X+Y}(s)=E[s^Xs^Y]$ is also $G_{X+Y}(s)=E[E[s^X\mid Y]s^Y]=E[\exp\{Y(s-1)\}s^Y]=E[t^Y]$ for $t$= $____$. Furthermore, for every $t$, $E[t^Y]=\exp\{\mu(t-1)\}$ hence $G_{X+Y}(s)=$ $______$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use that
$$
{\rm E}[s^{X+Y}]=\sum_{y=0}^\infty{\rm E}[s^{X+Y}\mid Y=y]\cdot P(Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^\infty s^y\cdot {\rm E}[s^X\mid Y=y]\cdot P(Y=y)
$$
along with the fact that $X\mid Y=y\sim \mathrm{po}(y)$.

Comment: Got a question about ${\rm E}[s^{X+Y}]=s^y\cdot {\rm E}[s^X\mid Y=y]$ -- did you use this property: ${\rm E}(XY|G)={\rm E}(X|G)Y$, where ${\rm E}(\cdot|G)$ commutes with multiplication by $G$-measurable variables [5th property](http://isfaserveur.univ-lyon1.fr/~stephane.loisel/prerequis_esp_cond.pdf)?

Comment: I used that: ${\rm E}[s^{X+Y}\mid Y=y]={\rm E}[s^{X+Y}1_{\{Y=y\}}]/P(Y=y)$ and on the set $\{Y=y\}$ we can replace $Y$ by $y$ and "pull out" $s^y$ since it is constant.

Comment: Can I assume that $s^Y$ is constant, because $Y$ has already happened? Sorry for dumb question.

Comment: No. $s^Y$ is of course a random variable, but $s^Y\cdot 1_{\{Y=y\}}=s^y\cdot 1_{\{Y=y\}}$, i.e. on the set $\{Y=y\}$ we know that $s^Y$ is just $s^y$ which is constant. That is: on the set $\{Y=y\}$ you may treat $Y$ as being constant (constantly equal to $y$ of course).

Comment: Understood. Thank you.